# How do I get next date by day of week and time

Tags: php, date, time, weekday

I want to get next class date by day of week and time. For example all classes are held on Tuesday and Saturday at 10:45pm
So I want to display date of next class to be held from current day/time.

Without time I am able to get. But what if today is Tuesday 4pm and class is Tuesday 10:45pm then it should show me today's date, and not Saturday as next class after today is Saturday.

I tried a test code with time but it is not working.

```
$nextTuesday = strtotime('next tuesday 10:59PM');
echo date('Y-m-d', $nextTuesday);
```

If I am giving time it is not working.

With time it should show current date if day is same and time has not passed.

Comment: what is the error message ?

Comment: I am afraid you can't do it in one statement.

Comment: no it is in two lines but got pasted in one line here

Comment: it does not show error. It shows me next tuesday 2019-01-22. But it should show me tuesday 2019-01-15 since its not yet 10:45

Comment: You have create your own logic.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I used my logic and solved it.

```
    date_default_timezone_set("ET");
    $currentday=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $currentdayW=date("l", strtotime($currentday));



    if (($currentdayW=="Tuesday") ||($currentdayW=="Friday"))
    {
    $chktime = date('Y-m-d 21:00:00');
    if ($chktime > $currentday) { $drawdate =  $chktime;}

    }

    if ((($currentdayW=="Tuesday") && ($chktime < $currentday)) || 
     ($currentdayW=="Wednesday") || ($currentdayW=="Thursday"))
    {
    $drawdate = strtotime('next friday');
    $drawdate=date('Y-m-d 21:00:00', $drawdate);
    }
    if ((($currentdayW=="Friday") && ($chktime < $currentday)) || 
    ($currentdayW=="Saturday") || ($currentdayW=="Sunday") || 
    ($currentdayW=="Monday"))
    {
     $drawdate = strtotime('next tuesday');
     $drawdate=date('Y-m-d 21:00:00', $drawdate);

     }

     echo $drawdate;
```